# How to configure UTF-8 on Velocity?

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, velocity

Using Java, Servlets, MySQL, Tomcat and Velocity, the following steps were taken:

- velocity.properties :

  - input.encoding=UTF-8
  - output.encoding=UTF-8
- server.xml

  - URIEncoding = UTF-8
- `<html><head>` Charset

  - meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;CHARSET=UTF-8"
- eclipse properties, project properties, file & editor encoding

  - set all that apply to UTF-8
- JDBC connection:

  - db.url=jdbc:mysql://:/?useEncoding=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
- java/servlet code:

  - request.setCharacterEncoding( UTF-8 )

All of the above didn't work. Until the following code was done:

```
private String getParameter(String key) {
    String param = request.getParameter(key);
        if (Util.isNotEmpty(param)) {
            try {
                return new String(param.getBytes("8859_1"), "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return param;
        }
    return null;
}
```

The above means that `request.setCharacterEncoding` didn't have an effect ( `getCharacterEncoding()` does return UTF-8 ); knowing that the request wrapper is wrapped in a `ThreadLocal` object.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: The symptoms indicate that you (or Velocity) didn't set the `charset` attribute in the HTTP response `Content-Type` header. Note that the `<meta>` tag is **ignored** when the page is served over HTTP. Instead, the charset attribute of the HTTP response Content-Type header will be used, if any. The `<meta>` tag is only used when the user saves the webpage to its local disk and then views it later from the disk on by `file:///`. Your problem needs likely to be solved in the Velocity side.

Comment: OK, so I extended VelocityLayoutServlet just to do set the response character encoding, and printed the header to get "Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8".
As I mentioned in the original post (before Admin's edit), this problem occurs from client to server and not the other way, that is when saving form data, hence, the positive effect of the function defined above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To interpret parameters correctly, the URL needs to be parsed as UTF-8 by tomcat. Set this in the server.xml connector properties, e.g. with:

```
<Connector port="8080"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000" 
               disableUploadTimeout="true" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the parameters encoded in the encoding the browser finds OK. Though, Problem might be based on a weird browser configuration or an xml header <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8895_1" ?> which might have been needed if this was once XHTML with iso encoding.